# Recursively find all subfolders' files and symlink them with their containing folder's name

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

Hopefully such a thing is possible, I would like to scan all the files in the subfolders of

```
/home/user/source/
```

and create symlinks to these files in a different folder with a different file extension. So I start with this folder structure:

```
/home/user/source/folder1/random_file_name.bin
/home/user/source/folder2/random_file_name.bin
/home/user/source/folder3/random_file_name.bin
...
```

And I would like to create symlinks to the bin files like such:

```
/home/user/dest/folder1.txt -> /home/user/source/folder1/random_file_name.bin
/home/user/dest/folder2.txt -> /home/user/source/folder2/random_file_name.bin
/home/user/dest/folder3.txt -> /home/user/source/folder3/random_file_name.bin
...
```

Can I do this in only one loop or must I scan each folder of "source" to extract the folder name then loop in each folder to find the bin file in each folder?
There's only one bin file per folder, with a random name by the way.

Unless there is a way to do this with the "find" command?

Comment: What should happen if there's a second file in, say, `folder1`?

Comment: I have no idea, I don't know if it can even happen. I guess the files of "folder1" would be in alphabetical order so the last one scanned would overwrite the symlink with -sf parameter, which is fine since the files contain a timestamp in the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for d in $(find source -type d); do ls $d/*.bin 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && ln -s $d/*.bin target/$(basename $d).dat;done
```

In slow-mo:

- Scan for the directories
- if the directory contains at least one .bin file
- link the bin file using the directory name

Comment: Wow all in one line thanks! And +1 for the explanations :)

Comment: This won't work if any of the directories contain spaces or other characters in `IFS` so be careful with this sort of answer